# Grupos de imágenes aleatorias

Tags: wordpress-imagenes

Hola tengo una pregunta algo compleja. Cómo sería un código que haga que se carguen random por ejemplo 2 imágenes a la vez en dos partes diferentes de la web.

Es decir que sean random, pero que cada vez que cargues la web salga un grupo de imágenes como 1,2,3,4 en distintas areas y luego que al recargar salgan 5,6,7,8. Es decir por ejemplo que el grupo uno tenga un nombre imágenes 1 y que el grupo dos tenga el nombre imágenes 2. Como las imágenes están en distintas areas creo que tendría que el sitio tener un código en cada area independiente que responda a un código que llame a cada imagen para que sea la que se vea.

Un ejemplo, pero lo que quiero es para varios grupos de imágenes.

```html
<div id="box">
    <a id="a"><img id="image" /></a>
</div>

<script type='text/javascript'> 
var images = 
[
    imageUrlPair = { ImgSrc:"1.jpg", Href:"http://ejemplo 1" },
    imageUrlPair = { ImgSrc:"2.jpg", Href:"http://ejemplo 2" },
    imageUrlPair = { ImgSrc:"3.jpg", Href:"http://ejemplo 3" },
    imageUrlPair = { ImgSrc:"4.jpg", Href:"http://ejemplo 4" },
]

function randImg() {
var size = images.length;
var x = Math.floor(size * Math.random());
var randomItem = images[x];
document.getElementById('image').src = randomItem.ImgSrc;
document.getElementById('a').href = randomItem.Href;
}

randImg();
</script>
```

Otro ejemplo

```html
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="javascript">
<!-- 
function makeArray(n) {
this.length = n;
for (var i=1; i<=n; i++) {
this[i] = ""; 
}
return this;
}
var i;
function imagealeatoire() {
i = Math.floor(3 * Math.random() + 1);
return image[i];
}
image = new makeArray(3);
image[1]="image_1.jpg";
image[2]="image_2.jpg";
image[3]="image_3.jpg";
// -->
</SCRIPT>

<SCRIPT language="javascript">document.write("<IMG SRC=" +imagealeatoire() +" WIDTH=200 HEIGHT=200 BORDER=0>");</SCRIPT>
```

Grupo de imágenes random 1

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Grupo de imágenes random 2

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola. Bienvenido a [es.so].  Te recomiendo [edit] la pregunta agregando algo de información como que has probado o que has encontrado por Internet, y sería bueno que realices el [tour] y leer [ask]. La idea es ofrecer un [mcve] en todas las preguntas.

Comment: Puse un ejemplo en imágenes, espero alguien me ayude. Gracias

Comment: Hola Alberto. Lo más importante es haberlo intentado. Sobre tu intento nos contextualizas en los problemas concretos que tienes y sobre ello podemos ayudarte. Si no lo has intentado, investiga y prueba. Después has de [edit] la pregunta para añadir la informacion que falta segun [ask] y [mcve]. Un saludo.

Comment: Podrías hacer un array con imágenes y elegir las que muestras con un random. Una vez elegidas, las quitas del array para que en la recarga salgan las otras que no has mostrado la primera vez

Comment: @albertoguerra cuando hablamos de [mcve], no nos referimos a que nos muestres unos pantallazos de tu pagina. Lo que queremos es que muestres el código que te da error, no comprendes o necesitas cambiar. Como pretendes que te ayuden si no saben que es lo que tienes. Es como ir a echar gasolina sin coche...

Comment: Hola Pablo. He visto muchos ejemplos de array similares, pero la verdad es que no conozco mucho del tema de los códigos

Comment: Pablo está muy cerca de lo que quiero, pero no tengo experiencias creando los array. Una vez ya tuve en una web algo así, pero no lo hice yo, y funcionaba genial, pero he perdido el contacto con quién me hizo el code y no tengo idea de como contactarlo

Answer (score 0):

el primer array supongo que contiene todas las imágenes posibles, no? Si ese es el caso la posibilidad que tienes primero, localiza cada grupo y guárdalos en un array (cada zona donde se supone que irán los grupos de imágenes sería una posición de ese array). Eso con un `querySelector()` o `querySelectorAll()` se hace fácil. Una vez localizadas esas zonas, separa las imágenes (Si quieres que se coloquen de forma aleatoria, pero que los grupos de imágenes sean siempre los mismos) creando arrays de imágenes dentro de otro array. Una vez hecho esto, ya simplemente asigna un grupo de imágenes a una zona de forma aleatoria y rellenalo.
Espero que haya sido de ayuda esta respuesta "conceptual".

Comment: La verdad me encantaría hacer lo que me dices, pero no tengo idea de cómo hacer algo así, aunque creo que es la idea

Comment: Cuando se llega a ese punto, lo que toca es investigar y aprender más programación, sobre todo desarrollar el pensamiento lógico necesario para programar.

Comment: Investigando llegué hasta aquí, pero parece que no llegaré muy lejos :( Creo que me tocará pagarle a alguien por que me haga o ayude con algo así, por que al parecer hasta para los expertos es algo complejo

Comment: Se me acaba de ocurrir, y si guardas cada grupo de imágenes en un archivo json, como objetos json (lógicamente), y al cargar la página cargues un archivo u otro de forma aleatoria (creas un array con los nombres de los archivos que tienen esos objetos json). Al elegir de forma aleatoria el nombre ya vas a tener cada vez un grupo aleatorio (dentro de cada grupo las imágenes no son aleatorias, pero al serlo el archivo, es como si lo fuesen), y ya simplemente cagar las imágenes con funciones del DOM (`createElement, append`, etc) o con jquery (`$(idContieneImg).append("crea IMG")`), o algo así.

Comment: Hola Enrique Manzano veo que tienes una idea interesante sobre esto. Hay alguna manera que te pueda contactar? Puede escribirme a este email. Se lo agradecería mucho eventos305@gmail.com

Comment: Buenas @albertoguerra , te he mandado un mail al correo que has proporcionado (Asunto: Contacto desde StackOverflow).